# How to construct the `When` condition for joining terminals?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Command for joining terminals: `workbench.action.terminal.joinInstance`.

Necessary conditions I can think of:

1. [Terminal tabs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_terminal-tabs) are focused.
2. Two or more terminals are selected in the terminal tabs.

The best I came up with is:

```sh
terminalProcessSupported && terminalTabsFocus && !terminalTabsSingularSelection
```

But the above is not the same as `terminalTabsMultipleSelections` (which doesn't exist).

Comment: `terminalTabsSingularSelection` is not mentioned at the when-clause doc page

Comment: @rioV8 It's already been used by `workbench.action.terminal.renameInstance`.

Comment: There is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/074b02d04b77bf8710dd49dd13383b5e244ae4c5/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/common/terminal.ts but I don't see anything helpful there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this fix](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/64ff30cf6351ba0d5ef5d4ad87b3821499016f25) in place, it's now safe to use `terminalProcessSupported && terminalTabsFocus` instead.

---

The original answer:

According to Daniel Imms's [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10546#issuecomment-864417475):

> We use internally to make it work in the context menu `terminalProcessSupported && !terminalTabsSingularSelection`

And the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/64ff30cf6351ba0d5ef5d4ad87b3821499016f25/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminalActions.ts#L1492) in this regard:

```
precondition: ContextKeyExpr.and(
  KEYBINDING_CONTEXT_TERMINAL_PROCESS_SUPPORTED,
  KEYBINDING_CONTEXT_TERMINAL_TABS_SINGULAR_SELECTION.toNegated(),
)
```

So for now, it's still best to use `terminalProcessSupported && terminalTabsFocus && !terminalTabsSingularSelection`.